# Woocommerce - hide product image for specific product category

Tags: php, woocommerce

Trying to hide product image on single product page for specific product category.

I found this "official" snippet: https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/remov-product-content-based-on-category/

But it doesn't work. Product image is still being displayed.

I also tried **woocommerce_show_product_thumbnails**
but same thing.

Anyone would know?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

As I am checking from your shared URL it's working fine. you should use category slug instead of the category name.

see below screenshot and code:

```
add_action( 'wp', 'remove_product_content' );
function remove_product_content() {
    // If a product in the 'Clothing' category is being viewed…
    if ( is_product() && has_term( 'clothing', 'product_cat' ) ) {
        //… Remove the images
        remove_action( 'woocommerce_before_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_show_product_images', 20 );
        // For a full list of what can be removed please see woocommerce-hooks.php
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for trying to help. Unfortunately this didn't help. Slug or name I tested, the product picture is still present...

Comment: As I am testing on my site with the category "clothing", It's 100% working on my website.

Comment: Could be possible that my theme is not calling the proper action to show product images? But I'm using an Astra theme. pretty standard...

Comment: No it's not possible, I  think the issue is has_term() function in your end. So first print term and check what is you getting

Comment: my knowledge is limited, how can I print term? thx

Comment: First of all search in google about get_term.   now sample code is: <?php $term = get_term_by('slug', 'my-term-slug', 'category'); echo "<pre>"; print_r($term); echo "</pre>"; ?>